# How can obtain the range of all solutions with CPLEX optimizer?

Tags: python, optimization, cplex, docplex

I am working on defining a diet model, to extract all possible solutions of diets with both environmental and nutritional constraints. I have used the same setup as in this docplex-example at GitHub to do the optimization and included environmental constraints as well:
[diet.py](https://github.com/IBMDecisionOptimization/docplex-examples/blob/master/examples/mp/modeling/diet.py)https://github.com/IBMDecisionOptimization/docplex-examples/blob/master/examples/mp/modeling/diet.py

Then, to obtain solutions from the pool of (non optimal) feasible solutions, I have added this part as well:

```
 def soln_pool(mdl):
     cpx = mdl.get_cplex()
     cpx.parameters.mip.pool.intensity.set(4)
     cpx.parameters.mip.limits.populate.set(1000000)
         
     try:
         cpx.populate_solution_pool()
     except CplexSolverError:
        print("Exception raised during populate")
        return []          
     numsol = cpx.solution.pool.get_num()
     print("The solution pool contains %d solutions." % numsol)
     meanobjval = cpx.solution.pool.get_mean_objective_value()
     print("The average objective value of the solutions is %.10g." % meanobjval)
     
     nb_vars = mdl.number_of_variables
     
     sol_pool = []

     for i in range(numsol):
        x_i = cpx.solution.pool.get_values(i)
        assert len(x_i) == nb_vars
        
        sol = []
        for k in range(nb_vars):
            sol.append(x_i[k])
        sol_pool.append(sol) 
     return sol_pool

results = soln_pool(mdl)
label=data.index
matrix_results=pd.DataFrame()
    
for s, sol in enumerate(results,start =1):
    matrix_results[str(s)]=sol
    matrix_results.index=data.index
```

I am interested to obtain the span/range of "all solutions" to see which diets can fulfill my criteria. Therefore I set Pool Intensity = 4 (aggressive) and the Populate limits = high number, to get as many solutions as possible. However, I sometimes get a very high number of solutions, and using 1000000 as the limit does not even retrieve all solutions. Since I am not interested in all solutions as such, but rather the "span" of solutions, I would like to achieve a pool of solutions, including both the best(optimised) and the worst solutions, while still seeing some steps in between. So, is it possible to skip some solutions with a step function, so that instead of getting all solutions, I get all solutions being at least x (e.g. 5) different from each other, and thereby reducing be pool?

Furthermore, it seems like, even though I put a high number, I do not always retrieve all solutions, e.g. I get 3000 solutions even though I know others exist. Does this mean that setting the population limit and intensity will not ensure that I get all solutions?

Finally, any other inputs/ideas to how I can setup such a model, will be highly appreciated!

Comment: The set of all diets may be difficult to describe. For some mathy background, you can look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_polytope): V-representation (each point is a combination of diets) vs. H-representation (each element is a vector of (protein, carb, fat)). Often, V-representation requires a lot more space than H-representation. You could compute upper and lower bounds on each of the input variables if you wanted to, but most solutions might end up unfeasible given your original constraints.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the solution pool replacement strategy

> Designates the strategy for replacing a solution in the solution pool
> when the solution pool has reached its capacity.

The docplex python parameter is parameters.mip.pool.replace

And with value 2

```
Replace solutions in order to build a set of diverse solutions
```

You could also [enumerate without solution pools](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zoodocplex/blob/master/zooenumeratewithoutsolutionpool.py):

```
mdl = Model(name='buses')
nbbus40 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus40')
nbbus30 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus30')
mdl.add_constraint(nbbus40*40 + nbbus30*30 >= 300, 'kids')
mdl.minimize(nbbus40**2*500 + nbbus30**2*400)

nb_iter=5

for iter in range(0,nb_iter):
    mdl.solve()
    nbbus40sol=int(nbbus40.solution_value)
    nbbus30sol=int(nbbus30.solution_value)
    print(int(nbbus40sol)," buses 40 seats")
    print(int(nbbus30sol)," buses 30 seats")
    print("cost : ",mdl.objective_value)
    print()
    mdl.add_constraint(mdl.logical_or((nbbus40sol!=nbbus40),
            nbbus30sol!=nbbus30))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Alex!
For solution 1, should this be added as a parameter both in the above and in the model?
For solution 2, which seems interesting, would you say it is also working for complex examples? For instance, I have more than 1000 food items with respectively 10 nutritional factors and 5 environmental factors, and each food item needs to fulfill both nutritional and environmental bounds. And the nb_iter, does that correspond with the Populate Limit in cplex?

Comment: Hi, sol 1 cpx.parameters.mip.pool.replace.set(2) . Sol 2 can also work with big model and nb_iter is the number of solutions you will get